# Activate USB tethering from the command line

Tags: adb, settings, shell, usb-tethering

I would like to activate USB tethering from within a bash script.

I've found `TetherSettings` action name from

```
aapt dump xmltree com.android.settings.apk AndroidManifest.xml | less +/ether
```

The following command open the needed settings, but don't change anything alone

```
am start -n com.android.settings/.TetherSettings
```

Is there any possibility to run a command line with `adb shell` to change it?

---

Related, but the opposite: [Is it possible to disable USB tethering from command line?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226828/is-it-possible-to-disable-usb-tethering-from-command-line)

Comment: That's really cool. I tried to find other commands doing `aapt dump xmltree com.android.settings.apk AndroidManifest.xml` but that didn't work on my phone(aapt not found). How can I see a list of the available settings ?

Comment: http://elinux.org/Android_aapt

Comment: Thanks! I've found aapt in the build-tools folder. I can run it now. I can't seem to find com.android.settings.apk though. I've tried: `find / -name 'com.android.settings.apk'` on the phone, but nothing came up :( Can you please let me know where I can find com.android.settings.apk ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your Android version has `svc` inbuilt utility, run this command:

```
adb shell svc usb setFunctions rndis
```

This would enable USB tethering. To see what other USB functions are available, run:

```
adb shell svc usb
```

Comment: *`setFunction` in first command

Comment: @Jortstek in the latest release of Android (version 12), it still continues to be `setFunctions`. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android12-release/cmds/svc/src/com/android/commands/svc/UsbCommand.java#39 It is possible the Android implementation by your  device's vendor removed the trailing `s` from the keyword.

Comment: Wow. Android 8 on Samsung device, it most definitely is without the "s". What ways they think of to trip people up.

Answer (score 20):

Running the following command as root should enable USB tethering:

- `service call connectivity 32 i32 1` on Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0)
- `service call connectivity 33 i32 1` on Jelly Bean (4.1 to 4.3)
- `service call connectivity 34 i32 1` on KitKat (4.4)
- `service call connectivity 30 i32 1` on Lollipop (5.0)
- `service call connectivity 31 i32 1` on Lollipop (5.1) according to [an answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/126499) by [Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord)
- `service call connectivity 30 i32 1` on Marshmallow (6.0), *untested*
- `service call connectivity 41 i32 1` on Samsung Marshmallow (6.0)
- `service call connectivity 33 i32 1` on Nougat (7.0)
- `service call connectivity 39 i32 1` on Samsung Nougat (7.0)

The first number you see in the commands is the `setUsbTethering()` method's number in [`IConnectivityManager.aidl`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/IConnectivityManager.aidl) (this depends on the Android version and doesn't exist on Gingerbread).

(Tip: to check this file for a particular Android version, select the appropriate branch.)

So what this command does is call `setUsbTethering()` and pass either 1 (enable USB tethering) or 0 (to disable it).

For more information, see [this related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226924/is-it-possible-to-usb-tether-an-android-device-using-adb-through-the-terminal).

---

If you're enabling USB tethering as part of a USB reverse tethering setup, `setprop sys.usb.config rndis,adb` should be more than enough to get the `rndis0` interface set up.

Comment: Looking at the jb-release branch, int setUsbTethering(boolean enable); looks to be the 33rd method, not 34th. Also, I've tested both the 4.1/4.2 and 4.3/4.4 commands on a Nexus 7 with JB 4.3 and service call connectivity **33** i32 1 turns on tethering.

Comment: This is the right answer for USBTethering. It won't work for WifiTethering though. The API hasn't been left open for that...

Comment: That  command for Android M works well on my stock Android 6.0.1 on Nexus 6. Good work keeping a list for multiple Android versions. I wish I could upvote it again.

Comment: Confirm that the MM command works on CM13 6.0.1 also. Thanks!

Comment: on CM14.1(7.1) the Jelly Bean command works

Comment: For Oreo (8.0): `service call connectivity 33 i32 1`

Answer (score 8):

There is a pretty bad method using `adb shell input tap`, Get the coordinates for enable tethering and substitute

```
adb shell input tap <x> <y>
```

Or navigate to enable radio using  `adb shell input keyevent`. Just have a look at,

```
adb shell input
```

Again this confines to a particular device.

Comment: Combining this all together, this works for me if the screen is unlocked: `adb shell "am start -n com.android.settings/.TetherSettings; input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_UP; input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER"`. I found a [list of key events](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8483797/817950) on SO.

Comment: In case anyone wants to test this out and/or modify it for their device, I'll post this here. I wrote [a little script](https://github.com/redbmk/bin/blob/master/tether) to turn on tethering for my nexus 5x (needs to be unlocked) and hooked it up to udev to do that automatically when I plug it in

Comment: @redbmk - thanks for the useful script.  For a *Galaxy A5 2017* the key sequence is: 

**${inputKey}DPAD_DOWN; $pause; ${inputKey}DPAD_DOWN; $pause; ${inputKey}ENTER**.  Also I found that **pause="sleep 0.3"** works ok.

Comment: In the sequence above I had forgot the initial key presses to dismiss the pop up confirmation about enabling MTP, which is **${inputKey}DPAD_DOWN; $pause; ${inputKey}DPAD_DOWN; $pause; ${inputKey}ENTER;**.

Answer (score 8):

Try the `setprop` command below:

```
setprop sys.usb.config rndis,adb
```

Comment: This is only part of what's needed. This won't start dnsmasq for instance.

Answer (score 4):

this is device independent (toggles USB tethering)

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.TetherSettings &&
adb shell input keyevent 20 &&
adb shell input keyevent 20 &&
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER &&
sleep 2 &&
adb shell input keyevent 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Modified to use windows timeout command instead of sleep, wake screen first, and only press down once. Twice down enabled wifi tethering on my phone.

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_WAKEUP && adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.TetherSettings && adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN && adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER && timeout 2 && adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK
```

Answer (score 2):

The `service` method did not work for me on my Samsung device. I figured out how to do it by configuring the network interface directly, though. Here is a script that sets up a Linux machine and a USB-connected rooted Android device for USB tethering. This does not set up DNS or NAT masquerading, but is sufficient to make the device accessible at 192.168.42.129:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

# Set up USB tethering for an Android device.
# Usage: adb-usb-tether [USB-VENDOR USB-PRODUCT]
# If USB vendor/product is unspecified, use first USB network interface.
# On the Android side, tethering is enabled via adb shell.

if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]
then
    any=false
    vendor=$1
    product=$2
else
    any=true
fi

function find_if() {
    local path if
    for path in /sys/class/net/*
    do
        if=$(basename "$path")
        if [[ "$(readlink "$path")" == */usb* ]]
        then
            local ifproduct ifvendor
            ifproduct=$(cat "$(realpath "$path")/../../../idProduct")
            ifvendor=$(cat "$(realpath "$path")/../../../idVendor")
            if $any || [[ "$ifproduct" == "$product" && "$ifvendor" == "$vendor" ]]
            then
                echo "Found interface: $if" 1>&2
                echo "$if"
                return
            fi
        fi
    done
}

function adb_shell() {
    adb shell "$(printf " %q" "$@")"
}

function adb_su() {
    local quoted
    quoted="$(printf " %q" "$@")"
    adb shell su -c "$(printf %q "$quoted")"
}

if=$(find_if)
if [[ -z "$if" ]]
then
    echo "Requesting interface:" 1>&2
    adb_su setprop sys.usb.config rndis,adb
    echo " >> OK" 1>&2
fi

while [[ -z "$if" ]]
do
    echo "Waiting for network device..." 1>&2
    sleep 1
    if=$(find_if)
done

while ! ( ip link | grep -qF "$if" )
do
    echo "Waiting for interface..." 1>&2
    sleep 1
done

function configure_net() {
    local name="$1"
    local if="$2"
    local ip="$3"
    local table="$4"
    local cmdq="$5" # Query command
    local cmdx="$6" # Configuration command

    if ! ( "$cmdq" ip addr show dev "$if" | grep -qF 192.168.42."$ip" )
    then
        echo "Configuring $name interface address:" 1>&2
        "$cmdx" ip addr add 192.168.42."$ip"/24 dev "$if"
        echo " >> OK" 1>&2
    fi

    if ( "$cmdq" ip addr show dev "$if" | grep -qF 'state DOWN' )
    then
        echo "Bringing $name interface up:" 1>&2
        "$cmdx" ip link set dev "$if" up
        sleep 1
        echo " >> OK" 1>&2
    fi

    if ! ( "$cmdq" ip route show table "$table" | grep -qF "192.168.42.0/24 dev $if" )
    then
        echo "Configuring $name route:" 1>&2
        "$cmdx" ip route add table "$table" 192.168.42.0/24 dev "$if"
        echo " >> OK" 1>&2
    fi
}

configure_net local  "$if"   128 main  command   sudo
configure_net device rndis0  129 local adb_shell adb_su
```

To enable forwarding (i.e. connect to the Internet from the PC via the Android device), see [my question and answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196482/configuring-usb-tethering-manually-with-root).