# Using ADB shell, How I can disable hotspot / tethering on lollipop Nexus 5

Tags: adb, wifi-hotspot, tethering

My screen got broken and I've been using my phone with a VNC Server installed on it, but this morning i'd the stupid idea of enable hotspot just to see if I can use my mobile data plan on my laptop, but when I did this, the wi-fi got disconnected from my router and now i only have access to my phone using adb shell.

I need to disable hotspot from ADB, already searched on google but didn't find anything, i also tried disable and enabling wi-fi, doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way to do it is by calling "service call" command.

For example on my phone I could call

```
# Start Wifi tethering
adb shell service call connectivity 24 i32 0 
# Stop Wifi tethering
adb shell service call connectivity 25 i32 0
```

`Service call` will call the function number `24` in connectivity service (which happened to be the function that turn on tethering) and pass it `0` as argument (`0` would be wi-fi tethering, 1 would be usb tethering and `2` would be bluetooth).

Sadly service functions code change from one android version to another. This stackoverflow reply explain how to get the right function code for your current android version.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227326/where-to-find-info-on-androids-service-call-shell-command

Also this is the functions list for connectivity service for the android version I am using (Nougat)
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-7.1.2_r1/core/java/android/net/IConnectivityManager.aidl

Comment: Looks like I'm missing some permissions, can see that in the parcel-log i get when executing the command

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say that you need to be rooted to be able to do this so you need to execute the "su"  command before running any of these.

Comment: Is it possible to set ap band through this method, please let me know how

Comment: I tried to do quick check but in modern android, the IConnectivityManager.aidl file is not there anymore to check. I don't know which file replaces it unfortunately

I'd suggest asking new question instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
  adb shell input keyevent 3 # home   

  adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings

  adb shell input keyevent 20 # down                                                   

  adb shell input keyevent 20 # down

  adb shell input keyevent 20 # down

  adb shell input keyevent 66 # enter

  adb shell input keyevent 20 # down

  adb shell input keyevent 20 # down

  adb shell input keyevent 66 # enter                                                 

  adb shell input keyevent 20 # down

  adb shell input keyevent 66 # enter
```

Comment: +1. This is helpful though in my CM12 I had to add some more keyevent 20 and 66 but it works well. Good!

Comment: By using this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29954/can-i-change-some-android-settings-from-the-command-line/98775#98775),  the solution can be decreased to just three steps :- `adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.TetherSettings` -> `adb shell input keyevent 20` -> `adb shell input keyevent 66 `. Done!

Comment: This worked for my Nexus 6 on Android 5.0 to enable WifiTether but I had to add one more keyevent 20. Seems 5.0+ has borked the ability to enable WifiTether from a Tasker plugin or from Tasker itself. There's really no am start command that will start hotspot directly?