# Recover broken smartphone

Tags: adb, 9.0-pie, broken-screen, xiaomi

My **Xiaomi Redmi Note 6 Pro** broke and 3/4 screen is completely black, I can't see anything but a little part below

[image]

Other than that, the touch doesn't work AND sometimes the screen triggers some random coordinate touch.
If that's not enough, Xiaomi devices must be unlocked at least 1 time after startup with pattern, but can't. I usually use biometric unlock such as fingerprint sensor and facial recognition but, again, can't.

I want to still use it anyways as a mobile hotspot. I managed to turn on mobile data on adb but, trying to activate hotspot like suggested in [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/197725), so `adb shell service call connectivity 24 i32 0`, I receive this output:

```
Result: Parcel(
0x00000000: fffffffc 00000019 00610063 006c006c '........c.a.l.l.'
0x00000010: 006e0069 00500067 0067006b 00630020 'i.n.g.P.k.g. .c.'
0x00000020: 006e0061 006f006e 00200074 00650062 'a.n.n.o.t. .b.e.'
0x00000030: 006e0020 006c0075 0000006c 00000330 ' .n.u.l.l...0...'
0x00000040: 00000193 00610009 00200074 006f0063 '......a.t. .c.o.'
0x00000050: 002e006d 006e0061 00720064 0069006f 'm...a.n.d.r.o.i.'
0x00000060: 002e0064 006e0069 00650074 006e0072 'd...i.n.t.e.r.n.'
0x00000070: 006c0061 0075002e 00690074 002e006c 'a.l...u.t.i.l...'
0x00000080: 00720050 00630065 006e006f 00690064 'P.r.e.c.o.n.d.i.'
0x00000090: 00690074 006e006f 002e0073 00680063 't.i.o.n.s...c.h.'
0x000000a0: 00630065 004e006b 0074006f 0075004e 'e.c.k.N.o.t.N.u.'
0x000000b0: 006c006c 00500028 00650072 006f0063 'l.l.(.P.r.e.c.o.'
0x000000c0: 0064006e 00740069 006f0069 0073006e 'n.d.i.t.i.o.n.s.'
0x000000d0: 006a002e 00760061 003a0061 00320031 '..j.a.v.a.:.1.2.'
0x000000e0: 00290038 0009000a 00740061 00610020 '8.).....a.t. .a.'
0x000000f0: 0064006e 006f0072 00640069 006e002e 'n.d.r.o.i.d...n.'
0x00000100: 00740065 0043002e 006e006f 0065006e 'e.t...C.o.n.n.e.'
0x00000110: 00740063 00760069 00740069 004d0079 'c.t.i.v.i.t.y.M.'
0x00000120: 006e0061 00670061 00720065 0065002e 'a.n.a.g.e.r...e.'
0x00000130: 0066006e 0072006f 00650063 00650054 'n.f.o.r.c.e.T.e.'
0x00000140: 00680074 00720065 00680043 006e0061 't.h.e.r.C.h.a.n.'
0x00000150: 00650067 00650050 006d0072 00730069 'g.e.P.e.r.m.i.s.'
0x00000160: 00690073 006e006f 00430028 006e006f 's.i.o.n.(.C.o.n.'
0x00000170: 0065006e 00740063 00760069 00740069 'n.e.c.t.i.v.i.t.'
0x00000180: 004d0079 006e0061 00670061 00720065 'y.M.a.n.a.g.e.r.'
0x00000190: 006a002e 00760061 003a0061 00300032 '..j.a.v.a.:.2.0.'
0x000001a0: 00330035 000a0029 00610009 00200074 '5.3.).....a.t. .'
0x000001b0: 006f0063 002e006d 006e0061 00720064 'c.o.m...a.n.d.r.'
0x000001c0: 0069006f 002e0064 00650073 00760072 'o.i.d...s.e.r.v.'
0x000001d0: 00720065 0043002e 006e006f 0065006e 'e.r...C.o.n.n.e.'
0x000001e0: 00740063 00760069 00740069 00530079 'c.t.i.v.i.t.y.S.'
0x000001f0: 00720065 00690076 00650063 0073002e 'e.r.v.i.c.e...s.'
0x00000200: 00610074 00740072 00650054 00680074 't.a.r.t.T.e.t.h.'
0x00000210: 00720065 006e0069 00280067 006f0043 'e.r.i.n.g.(.C.o.'
0x00000220: 006e006e 00630065 00690074 00690076 'n.n.e.c.t.i.v.i.'
0x00000230: 00790074 00650053 00760072 00630069 't.y.S.e.r.v.i.c.'
0x00000240: 002e0065 0061006a 00610076 0033003a 'e...j.a.v.a.:.3.'
0x00000250: 00300033 00290038 0009000a 00740061 '3.0.8.).....a.t.'
0x00000260: 00610020 0064006e 006f0072 00640069 ' .a.n.d.r.o.i.d.'
0x00000270: 006e002e 00740065 0049002e 006f0043 '..n.e.t...I.C.o.'
0x00000280: 006e006e 00630065 00690074 00690076 'n.n.e.c.t.i.v.i.'
0x00000290: 00790074 0061004d 0061006e 00650067 't.y.M.a.n.a.g.e.'
0x000002a0: 00240072 00740053 00620075 006f002e 'r.$.S.t.u.b...o.'
0x000002b0: 0054006e 00610072 0073006e 00630061 'n.T.r.a.n.s.a.c.'
0x000002c0: 00280074 00430049 006e006f 0065006e 't.(.I.C.o.n.n.e.'
0x000002d0: 00740063 00760069 00740069 004d0079 'c.t.i.v.i.t.y.M.'
0x000002e0: 006e0061 00670061 00720065 006a002e 'a.n.a.g.e.r...j.'
0x000002f0: 00760061 003a0061 00380033 00290031 'a.v.a.:.3.8.1.).'
0x00000300: 0009000a 00740061 00610020 0064006e '....a.t. .a.n.d.'
0x00000310: 006f0072 00640069 006f002e 002e0073 'r.o.i.d...o.s...'
0x00000320: 00690042 0064006e 00720065 0065002e 'B.i.n.d.e.r...e.'
0x00000330: 00650078 00540063 00610072 0073006e 'x.e.c.T.r.a.n.s.'
0x00000340: 00630061 00280074 00690042 0064006e 'a.c.t.(.B.i.n.d.'
0x00000350: 00720065 006a002e 00760061 003a0061 'e.r...j.a.v.a.:.'
0x00000360: 00330037 00290035 0000000a          '7.3.5.).....    ')
```

I also wanted to install an application on the phone to control it through the pc, but can't because it needs confirmation from phone itself.

After I tried to use a [screen unlocker bash file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30012642/13029547) (through windows ubuntu subsystem) and, finding the coordinates for the points, the screenshots from the phone lock screen are blank so I can't see which coordinates they are.

After that I also tried to use [AdbControl](https://marian.schedenig.name/2014/07/03/remote-control-your-android-phone-through-adb/) (written in Java), which should stream the phone to the pc , but it gives me errors for every single frame.

I tried also **Mi Suite** with no luck: although I connected my device it shows this:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for **adbcontrol** you must escape backslash in windows path and specify a writeable path on device for example `/storage/emulated/0` which probably fails because location isn't available during unlock/decryption. depending on permissions you can maybe use external MicroSD card instead

```
adbCommand = C:\\platform-tools\\adb.exe
screenshotDelay = 100
localImageFilePath = C:\\adbcontrol\\adbcontrol_screenshot.png
phoneImageFilePath = /storage/4D47-9860/adbcontrol_screenshot.png
```

---

**you can also use [scrcpy](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc) instead**

---

another **manual method** for unlock/decryption (only works for password)

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_SPACE
adb shell input text <password>
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER
```

---

another option is **physical keyboard** connected via usb-otg adapter

Comment: btw you are lucky that you previously enabled usb-debugging :)

Comment: Yes, I made some apps and needed to do it ;) btw I haven't got an OTG, I'm gonna try the first two methods

Comment: I am getting [this](https://pastebin.com/MuWUBf6N) error and [this](https://pastebin.com/ttFwsrJ4) is config. I watched the source code and there shouldn't be errors...

Comment: changed to  /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ADBC/adbcontrol_screenshot.png. This doesn't resolve anything: exact same error

Comment: Thank you so much, with scrcpy works the first time! The last thing I ask you is: how can I disable touch since the phone, with the broken screen, keeps interfering with the touch?

Comment: Can't find a way to do this, I made another post to solve this "forever", but I found a temporary solution since all I want now is the hotspot and I managed to activate it. Thank you again!

Comment: `scrcpy --turn-screen-off`