# Why I get permission denied on ADB on Android phone?

Tags: adb, permissions, broken-screen

I'm trying to cast my Android device to a PC with `adbcontrol` (tutorial [here](https://marian.schedenig.name/2014/07/03/remote-control-your-android-phone-through-adb/)). The phone has a broken (black) screen and when I input the command `java -jar adbcontrol.jar` I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException:Cannot run program..error=13, Permission denied.
```

I have Java version: OpenJDK version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04

I tried getting permissions with `chmod +rwx` of the folder where `adbcontrol.jar` is located but the error persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the phone rooted?

Comment: No,the phone is not rooted

Comment: I'm on LInux Mint.I have two android phones,the one with broken screen has USB Debugging disabled,and on the other phone is enabled but the error is the same.

Comment: I do have adb from Android SDK

Comment: You should state what Android version your devices are using. If the Android devices are 5.0+ then I would recommend [scrcpy](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207688/3573)

Comment: Yes,one of them is lollipop 5.1(Samsung Galaxy j3 2016) but has USB debugging disabled so scrcpy will not work,while the other one is an Xiaomi Redmi 9a and i managed to cast it with scrcpy

Comment: you can try to root or flash something with heimdall https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228280
https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230999

Comment: get some combination firmware according to your phone model that will help you to get adb enabled. don't use [odin](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220570). don't flash pit file or param. make sure to only flash system kernel recovery via heimdall (otherwise your userdata get erased) https://gsmfirms.com/product/samsung-j320fn-combination-file-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before actually running `adbcontrol` you must specify paths in config file

check adb connection is working fine (previously authorized) and find a writeable location on device, for example

```
/sdcard
/storage/emulated/0
/data/local/tmp
```

depending on encryption and lock screen the location might not be available in this boot state, so better double check `adb push` is working

```
adb push ~/file.txt /sdcard
```

now open the `config.properties` file and define paths

```
adbCommand = adb
screenshotDelay = 100
localImageFilePath = adbcontrol_screenshot.png
phoneImageFilePath = /sdcard/adbcontrol_screenshot.png
```

if your adb binary is not in env you must specify path in first line. for windows paths backslash should escaped like

```
adbCommand = C:\\Android\\platform_tools\\adb.exe
```

when configured you can finally run adbcontrol from command line. the terminal will floated by debugging log (you can minimize). another window will open showing your phone screen. your keyboard and mouse input is recognized in android now

```
java -jar adbcontrol.jar
```

Comment: while running this on SGJ3 2016 i get: 'adb push ~/file.txt /sdcard' i get this:adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/emulators found.This is how my config look like:'adbCommand = /media/enq/5F53DF292609C82D/Kit/LinuxStuff/adbcontrol/adbcontrol.jar
screenshotDelay = 100
localImageFilePath = /home/enq/adbcontrol_screenshot.png
phoneImageFilePath = /mnt/sdcard/adbcontrol_screenshot.png'

Comment: I've managed to cast Xiaomi with adbcontrol(after folowing your instructions and typing "which adb"(it was in usr/bin/adb),but how to control the phone from pc?

Comment: Ok,thank you so much

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224214