# How unlock very old phone (Xperia X10) using ADB?

Tags: adb, lock-screens, usb-debugging

I have a very old Xperia X10 phone with a broken touch (you can see everything on the screen). I would like to recover an important video from it (it is on the phone's memory, not on the SD card).
I tried to do it using ADB, but there is no swipe or touchscreen function to unlock the screen in such an old android. The only possible inputs are:

```
$ input                                                   
       usage: input [text|keyevent]                                     
       input text <string>                                       
       input keyevent <event_code>
```

Input codes work because I can enter numbers, * and # in emergency number mode. I can't download it using pull because I don't have *root* and thus access to the *data* folder.

Comment: If the phone supports USB OTG then your best chance is to connect a simple USB mouse + adapter to the phone, then you will get a mouse cursor that can trigger the same functions like a touch.

Comment: @Robert I tried using the mouse, unfortunately it does not work in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recover broken smartphone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224214/recover-broken-smartphone)

Comment: @alecxs Unfortunately no, I have to perform a slide to unlock the phone. This is not the case in the example given.

Comment: *'input keyevent KEYCODE_SPACE'* does slide on my devices, your android version is probably ancient

Comment: @alecxs That's right, the default android version on this phone is 1.9